# How to copy (deep) whole struct into another one with all its members? (edited to make easier the goal)

Tags: c, struct

I have :

```
typedef struct emm_packet_t // original struct 1
{
uchar           emm[258];
int16_t         emmlen;
uchar           caid[2];
uchar           provid[4];
uchar           hexserial[8];
uchar           type;
} EMM_PACKET;
```

Consider that all the members of struct have dynamic values it keeps changes whenever do_emm is called from other location in code ...

```
copy_function(EMM_PACKET *ep)
{

// here I wanna copy EMM_PACKET *ep to EMM_PACKET_s *ep_s
// if I do simple assignment like

EMM_PACKET_s *ep_s;

ep = ep_s; // I get warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type


// if I use memcpy the whole program crashes ... 

EMM_PACKET_s = EMM_PACKET; // this also not working 
}


static int do_emm(EMM_PACKET *ep)
{

copy_function(ep); // calling copy function with passing ep ...
}
```

Should I copy member by member?

I am sure I am doing it the wrong way. Please point me in the correct direction — how do I copy the struct into another one or how to make 2nd instance or just *ep into another one say *ep_s for permanent use.

if i assign *ep to ep_s both becomes equal but since ep values remain changing it also effect ep_s whenever ep value change ep_s also changes , i want to have static values in ep_s , ep_s value must change only when i call copy function else it must remain the same until i call copy function again.

in simple words i want to copy/store *ep into another one say *ep_s , if i just pass it by function it make a copy of stuct but ep value remain changes and it also effect ep_s so i want to store ep_s permanently in memory may be .. i am noob sorry most of the comments goes above by head lol .. thanks

=================================================================================

```
static EMM_PACKET *ep_s; // Globally Declared


typedef struct emm_packet_t // original struct
{
uchar           emm[258];
int16_t         emmlen;
uchar           caid[2];
uchar           provid[4];
uchar           hexserial[8];
uchar           type;
} EMM_PACKET;


copy_function(EMM_PACKET *ep)
{

ep_s = ep; // This works but values of EMM_PACKET ep members are keep changing , and it also effect ep_s value.

// when i call function first time from do_emm it bring the ep in here
and points it correctly to ep_s if i print the vlaues of member its comes equal/correct
   but do_emm(EMM_PACKET *ep) values keep changes and it keep points to ep_s ,
   i want to store the value of ep into ep_s when i call copy function only, this the reason
   i wana deep copy of store the value of ep_s so it remain constant untill i again
   call copy function.




}


static int do_emm(EMM_PACKET *ep) // its being called rapidly from other parts of the program
{


if(ep->type == SHARED && ep->emm[0] == 0x83) // i call copy function only in certain condition
{

copy_function(ep); // calling copy function with passing required ep to be copied to global EMM_PACKET ep_s ...

}

}
```

- have edited again for more clarification ... thank you all !

Comment: If you have to use same members, why don't you use multiple     
instances of the same structure instead of creating another   
structure.

Comment: hi thans for reply , the value of EMM_PACKET *ep keeps change , if i simply pass ep_s it also remain changing whenever ep value change ... thats why i wana copy ep value to another ep_s , ep_s must remain static. sorry i dont understand using of multiple instances , i am not sure about members names should i change them or not but 2nd stuct or ep_s i want must have all these same members.

Comment: You can still do it using multiple instances of the same structure.  
I am trying to explain it with some code..see you in a while..

Comment: "if i use memcpy the whole programe crashes" - because you copy to a *pointer*; you need to allocate the memory first. "strcpy also produces errors" -- you seriously tried that?

Comment: Does your "deep" copy also need the `client` data copied? (This depends on what you do with it. If you do not copy it, freeing it "from" one struct makes the original pointer invalid for the copy.)

Comment: hi, i dont have string.h included though i have tried copy emm[258] member strcpy(ep_s->emm,ep->emm); // warning: implicit declaration of function 'UNSAFE_STRCPY_USE_CS_STRNCPY_INSTEAD' client data i dont need , i need to copy mainly emm[258] and type these 2 member are enough because other member values remain same and copy is not needed.

Comment: Note that you show two different types, albeit with the same structure content, but the two `typedef`s do not define any variables.  Since the types are the same apart from the tag, there is little point in having both types, especially if you need to copy one type to the other.  If you use `memcpy()` correctly, it should work.  A 'deep copy' would have to know how to clone the `struct s_client` from the pointer in the original.

Comment: Note that each separate structure type has its own namespace for the members; that change was made in C years before I started using it — and that's been a very long time (1983).  (Once upon a long time ago, somewhere in the early to mid 1970s, structure members had to be unique amongst all structures in a program.  It was fairly quickly found to be unmanageable.)  At the point in your question where you ask 'Has another block of memory been allocated for 2nd struct?' the answer is "No; no memory has been allocated for either struct".  You've defined the types, but no variables of either type.

Comment: `EMM_PACKET_s` is not defined anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how structures work.

First of all when all the members of the two structures are exactly same, then there is
no point creating a new structure, you can simply have another instance (or variable)
of the same structure and continue.
As far as your problem is concerned, consider this example :

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct one
{
   int member1;
   int member2;
   char member3;
};


int main()
{
   struct one var_one, var_two;

   /* Assigning values to the members of instance "var_one" */    
   var_one.member1 = 1;
   var_one.member2 = 2;
   var_one.member3 = 'a';

   /* to copy the values of one instance into another just use assignment operator */
   var_two = var_one;

   /* Now trying to access the values using "var_two" */
    printf("member1 = %d, member2 = %d, member3 = %c\n", var_two.member1,var_two.member2  
    var_two.member3);


    return 0;
}
```

You can also use pointers where i have used simple instances, but then you will have to
pass references to those pointers to access values in other functions.

Getting into your code :

```
P : stands for problem.        
S : for solution.
```

Corrections :

```
       ep = ep_s;

P1 :as per the requirement this assignment is wrong.           
P2 :Even after correcting the assignment you will still get the warning.
```

S1 :

Since you want to copy EMM_PACKET *ep to EMM_PACKET_s *ep_s, for that you should
have instance of type EMM_PACKET_s *ep_s on the left side of assignment, and the
instance of type EMM_PACKET *ep on the right side, because the assignment operator works
from right to left i.e. value on the right side is assigned to the variable on the left
side. Also it is must to have a variable on the left side but on the right side you can
have a variable or a constant.

S2 :

This assignment gives you warning, because the assignment operator expects that the       operands present on both sides must have same data type or compatible data types.
We need compatible data types for casting one type of instance( rvalue ) into another
( lvalue ).
rvalue and lvalue refer to the values on the right and the left side of the assignment
operator.

Here on the left side of the operator you have an pointer to instance of type EMM_PACKET
where as on the right side you have a pointer to instance of type EMM_PACKET_s.

In order to remove the warning you need to have same types of instances on both the 
sides.

```
P3 :EMM_PACKET_s = EMM_PACKET; // this also not working
```

S3 :

This is not working because this is not supposed to work.
You cannot use two data types on the either sides of an assignment operator.
"=" is an assignment "operator" and by definition an operator operates on "operands" and
not on their data types.

A better approach to your problem would be :

You dont need to create a separate method to copy structures (not for same strutures
   at least).

```
static int irdeto_do_emm(EMM_PACKET *ep, EMM_PACKET *ep_s)
{
/* I am assuming that "ep"  and "ep_s" have already been malloc'd */        

  ep_s = ep; // now the pointer ep_s starts to point to the address inside "ep"       
  }
```

Comment: @OScam - If you want to play around with pointers then make sure   
you have allocated memory where the pointers need to point else    
you are most likely to get segmentation faults.

Comment: hi i tried creating 2nd instance but i cant do it for some reason as like:   struct EMM_PACKET ep, ep_s; OR  struct emm_packet_t ep, ep_s; but it will say redeclation of ep as i have EMM_PACKET *ep in function already that i passed from main function and cant change it :( anyway i am still trying to make 2nd instance by adjusting code.